# Insert a element from php variable in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string, associative-array

I have a conditional string like this:

```
echo $cnd = "'use_funds'=>'no'";
```

And my `$data` array is :

```
$data = array(
    $cnd,
    'quantity'   => $_POST['qty_' . $q],
    'veg_name'   => $_POST['veg_name_' . $q],
    'rate'       => $_POST['rate_' . $q],
    'ws_price'   => $_POST['ws_price_' . $q],
    'ret_price'  => $_POST['ret_price_' . $q],
    'mop'        => $_POST['mop_' . $q],
    'ret_margin' => $_POST['ret_margin_' . $q]
);
```

The above `echo $cnd` shows `'use_funds'=>'no'`, but the `var_dump($data)` shows `array
  0 => string ''use_funds'=>'no'' (length=17)` . And since its a string my data is not inserting in my table. How can I make the `$cnd` to a associative array element instead of string?

Comment: Why does `$cnd` contain PHP code? Wouldn't it make more sense to have something like `$use_funds = 'no'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (your condition) {
  $data['use_funds'] = 'no';
} else {
  //some other code
}
```

Comment: Hi Nithish, if you got solution, then accept RST answer. Dont open this question

Answer (score 2):

don't use the $cnd part to make and insert the data in the array:

Use the below code:

```
$data['use_funds'] = 'no';
```

And this code will append the array.
OR you can use the [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function of PHP.

Comment: Note that `array_push`ing an associative array doesn't work as you'd expect (http://codepad.org/b4of4dml)

Comment: @PhpMyCoder ok, Then I can suggest `array_merge` by making two array and merge them.

Comment: Sounds better. +1 on the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If it must be a string, split it and add it to the array.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

The explode function takes a string and breaks it into an array

```
$my_string_split = explode('=>', $cnd);
// returns [0 => 'use_funds', 1 => 'no']
$data[$my_string_split[0]] = $my_string_split[1];
```

If it does not need to be a string, do it literally:

```
$data['use_funds'] = 'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your `$cnd` is string , not an array. and you are trying to append this `$cnd` with `$data` array.

for adding element to an array we basically use `push()` method. For your case if you use `array_push` method then you will get a output like below

```
array_push($cnd,$data);
$data=array(
                                    0=>'use_funds'=>'no',
                                    'quantity'=>$_POST['qty_'.$q],
                                    'veg_name'=>$_POST['veg_name_'.$q],
                                    'rate'=>$_POST['rate_'.$q],
                                    'ws_price' => $_POST['ws_price_'.$q],
                                    'ret_price' => $_POST['ret_price_'.$q],
                                    'mop' => $_POST['mop_'.$q],
                                    'ret_margin' =>$_POST['ret_margin_'.$q]
  );
```

so my suggession will be if you want you desire result then follow below step:-

```
 either define your $cnd as an array and then use array_merge();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $cnd = "'use_funds'=>'no'";
```

The above line considers `"'use_funds'=>'no'"` as a string and assigns it to `$cnd`. So no matter what, it always remains as a string unless you make any proper change to it. The default key in that case will be `0`. So, it will be like:

```
[0] => "'use_funds'=>'no'"
```

To get around this problem, you can do this:

```
$cnd = array('use_funds'=>'no');
```

Then, you an use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php%E2%80%8E) function to merge the two like this:

```
array_merge($cnd, $data);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish it using `eval`

```
$cnd = "'use_funds'=>'no'";

eval("\$x = array($cnd);");

print_r($x);
```

Comment: Please don't use eval, it attempts to interpret the given string as code and as such is very unsafe, specifically in conditions where the string is not known to be good. Best to just leave it be, regardless, there's almost always a safer way to get the result.

Comment: `eval` has it's uses. this situation is a pre-defined input so there is no safety concern. my solution didn't change any of his current setup. Everyone else assumes that he didn't know about the usual array key addition.